# Traverse to parent item that matches the given template id using Sitecore Powershell Extension

Tags: powershell-extensions

I want to find the ancestor of an item that matches the given template id using Powershell. Can anyone help me in achieving this?

**Scenario:** I'm on Item A, I get the current item details using `gi .`. From item A I want to navigate upwards and find the ancestor with matching TemplateID.

**Example:**

Home

```
-- Parent 1 

  -- Parent 2

     -- Item A
```

Comment: Can you provide more details with an example if possible

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your requirement, you want to find all items related to a known template ID. The phrasing is a bit confusing so it would be helpful if you can clarify the statement.

**Example:** Given an item, find all items matching the same Template ID which are children of the given item parent. In other words, find all items with the same template as **Home** which fall under the **Content** node (parent of **Home**).

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:\content\home"
$templateItem = Get-ItemTemplate -Item $item
Get-ItemReferrer -Item $templateItem | 
    Where-Object { $_.ItemPath.StartsWith($item.Parent.Paths.Path) }
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood right, which is 'find the ancestor that matches the current item's template' (the opposite of Michael's answer :-) ), you could use the below script:

```
$currentItem = Get-Item -Path '/sitecore/content/Home/'
$templateId = "" #Place your target template ID here
$currentItem.Name

$item = $currentItem
while($item.Parent){
    $item.Parent.Name
    if($item.Parent.TemplateId -eq $templateId){
        "done. item.Parent is what you're looking for"
        $item.Parent.Id #target item's ID
        break
    }
    $item = $item.Parent
}
```

You will have to set the `$currentItem` and `$templateId` to match your scenario

Comment: no @TamerM, the templateid of the parent is different. actually in a tree of items, my item is in the end, i want to navigate and find the parent's belongs to different templates and get their Item ID.

Comment: @TamerM, if you can, just update your answer so the `$templateId` is hardcoded to something. @Prakash just wants to know when sitting at a random item, walk up the tree until you find a known template ID.

Comment: @Prakash I updated the answer by making the template ID static. You will have to put in your template ID to search for

Comment: @TamerM thanks for the help and found an alternate way in getting the templateID details

$currentItemId = gi . #get current item 

$currentItemPath = $currentItemId.ItemPath #retrieve item path
$splitedArray = $path -split '/' #perform split operation 
$pathBuilder = ""
foreach($result in $splitedArray)
{
    $pathBuilder = ($pathBuilder)+'/'+$result
    $itemDetails = gi -Path master:/$pathBuilder
    $templateId = $itemDetails.TemplateId
 if($templateId -eq "")#pass the desired templateId here
 {
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the way using the Item path and traversed the tree and found the template Id

```
$currentItemId = gi . #get current item 
$currentItemPath = $currentItemId.ItemPath #retrieve item path
$splitedArray = $path -split '/' #perform split operation 
$pathBuilder = ""
foreach($result in $splitedArray)
{

$pathBuilder = ($pathBuilder)+'/'+$result
$itemDetails = gi -Path master:/$pathBuilder
$templateId = $itemDetails.TemplateId
if($templateId -eq "")#pass the desired templateId here
{
 #..
}
}
```

Thanks a ton for @TamerM and @Michaell West